# fontawesome icon are not rendering correctly on google chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, font-awesome

I am using following code snippet that use [fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/icon/sign-in/) to indicate Login and Register icons:

```
<a href="http://My-App-Local.dev/login"><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Login</a>
```

But it renders as below on Chrome browser:

[image]

However, in firefox the same code renders like below:

[image]

> Why is it not rendering correctly in chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the font isn't loaded in Chrome. The reason must be the `<script>` tag in the header which contains the link to fontawesome.com - check if there are any typos, missing quotes or similar in there. (Firefox might be more tolerant to typos/missing characters in that particular situation)